# JWT TokenValidationParameters problem with ValidAudiences

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using JWT in an ASP.NET Core web api (.NET Core 3.1) with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.
I have two projects set up as follows:

**MyProj.Identity** and **MyProj.Server**.
I've defined 2 roles: "admin" and "user". I would like to authorise the calls to MyProj.Server controllers with tokens generated by MyProj.Identity for users in role "user". I would also like to authorise some calls to MyProj.Identity with tokens generated by MyProj.Identity for users in role "admin".
In MyProj.Identity I have the following controller:

```
namespace MyProj.Identity.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/authentication")]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {           
        //...
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto model)
        {
            //...
        }
        
        [Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegistrationInfo registrationInput)
        {
            //...
        }
        
        [Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
        [HttpPost("register-admin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin([FromBody] RegistrationInfo registrationInput)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

In MyProj.Server there are controllers like the following:

```
namespace MyProj.Server.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.User)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/items")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        //...
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ItemDto>>> Get()
        {
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

The Startup in both projects has the following configuration

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

    // Adding Jwt Bearer  
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            ValidAudiences = Configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudiences").Get<string[]>(),
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    //...
}
```

In the appsettings.json for both projects there is:

```
"JWT": {
    "ValidIssuer": "http://MyProj.Identity.Url",
    "ValidAudiences": [
      "http://MyProj.Identity.Url",
      "http://MyProj.Server.Url" 
    ],
    "Secret": "MySecret",
    "TokenExpiryMinutes": "120"
  }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I set the **ValidAudiences** property in the TokenValidationParameters, the token that is generated upon Login doesn't have any "aud" set (inspecting it with https://jwt.io/) and authorisation fails as a consequence. If I set the **ValidAudience** property instead (single audience), everything works fine but I'm not able to authorise more than one audience. I tried setting the "ValidAudiences" property manually from a list as well (not from config), but the result was the same. I seem to be missing something with regards to the multiple valid audiences. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was right in front of me :).

The Login method in MyProj.Identity (which generates the token) needs to include auth claims for each of the audiences, as follows:

```
namespace MyProj.Identity.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/authentication")]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        // ...
        
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto model)
        {
            // ...
            foreach (var audience in _configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudiences").Get<string[]>())
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, audience));
            }
            // ...
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(_configuration["JWT:TokenExpiryMinutes"])),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

This solves the problem.